# Oracle search list of words in string and retruen existing ones

Tags: oracle

I am trying to write a statistic about the data warehouse tables that are used.

Therefor I should make a query to bring the used tables.

I have a list of table names and I have a database table, where the querys stored in.

How can I select the rows with the table names that used in?

```
Report Table:
...
QUERYTEXT String
...


select * from Report where QUERETEXT (?)

DWTableNames: DWA, DWB,..
```

I want to print each Report with the data warehouse table names that are existing in the querytext field.

Comment: This will be a difficult project (probably hopeless). Here is just one reason for it: A query may reference a table indirectly. It may select from a view, but the view itself reads from the base table. Do you want to write your solution, so that if a view is found in a query, then the view definition is also parsed to see what tables IT uses? Then: You may have a recursive WITH clause; a table may be read many times in that kind of query, but the text of the query only references the table name once. How do you want to count then?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - your point being? I gave just one example of why the project doesn't quite make sense (and I gave one more example in that comment). There are many more. No matter how many of these "special situations" we fix, there will be more that are not addressed.

Comment: Well if you need a real `statistic` i.e. not exact, but also not to wrong results you may try this approach. 1) perform `Explain plan`for all you queries. 2) Check all values `OBJECT_OWNER` and  `OBJECT_NAME` from  the `plan_table` against your list. 3) You'll have to map used indices to tables and views to base tables using `dba_indexes` resp. `DBA_DEPENDENCIES`. Good luck!

Comment: @mathguy sorry I didn't red the title,  that apprach make definitive less sense. See my point in above comment.

Comment: @mathguy, thanks for your answer.
I think, I don't have a recursive here.
you can see the explained use case in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I searched for:

```
WITH dwtables(dwtable) AS (
  SELECT 'DWA' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DWB' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DWC' FROM dual

)--> Tabelle mit einem Spalte (Liste)

SELECT title, 
    (SELECT LISTAGG (dwtable, ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY dwtable)
     FROM dwtables
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (r.querytext, '(^|\s)'||dwtables.dwtable||'(\s|$)', 'i')) AS dwtables

 FROM Reports r;
```

Comment: Some examples that may fool your *word scan* approach: `select /* DWA */ * from comple_other_table;`  `select * from comple_other_table DWB;` `select DWC from comple_other_table;`

Answer (score 0):

**Simple approach to extract the table names from a list of SQL queries**

**Setup**
Let's suppose this is your query list:

```
select * from a where id = 1;
select * from v;
with my_id as (select id from b)
select  /*+ PARALLEL(4) */ * from a where id in (select id from my_id);
```

To cover also the view access, here is the table definition:

```
create table a (id number);
create index a_idx  on a(id);

create table b (id number);
create table c (id number);
create table d (id number);

create view v as
select c.id from c join d on c.id = d.id;
```

So there are tables `a, b, c and d` and `v` is view on `c and d`

*As a result you want so see a list of tables `a, b, c and d`, even that in your query list only the tables `a, b` are directly referenced.

**Solution**

In the *first step* convert your query list in a list of `EXPLAIN PLAN` statements. You may find it practicable to use some sort of scripting if the list is of non-trivial length:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'q1' into   plan_table  FOR select * from a where id = 1;
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'q2' into   plan_table  FOR select * from v; 
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'q3' into   plan_table  FOR with my_id as (select id from b)
select  /*+ PARALLEL(4) */ * from a where id in (select id from my_id);
```

Through execution the `EXPLAIN PLAN` statements the `plan_table` is filled with the execution plans and accessed objects are for each operation are stored in columns `OBJECT_OWNER, OBJECT_NAME`.

The first naive query returns this list:

```
select distinct  OBJECT_OWNER,  OBJECT_NAME  
from plan_table 
where statement_id in ('q1','q2','q3') and OBJECT_NAME is not NULL
order by 1,2;

OBJECT_OWNER OBJECT_NAME
------------ -----------
DWH          A_IDX       
DWH          B           
DWH          C           
DWH          D           
SYS          :TQ10000    
SYS          :TQ10001    
SYS          :TQ10002
```

Two things must be fixed. 
First the row sources for parallel execution must be ignored (e.g. `:TQ10000`) as they are not a real tables. 
Second the index names (e.g. `A_IDX`) must be mapped to table_names using the dictionary view `DBA_INDEXES`.

Note that you need not take a special care for views, as they are parsed automatically to the source tables. The same is true for the *subquery factoring* (`with` clause).

The query approaching both topics is shown below:

```
select distinct OBJECT_OWNER, 
/* map index name to table name */
case when p.OPERATION = 'INDEX' then i.TABLE_NAME else p.OBJECT_NAME end as TABLE_NAME  
from plan_table p
left outer join dba_indexes i on p.OBJECT_OWNER = i.OWNER and p.OBJECT_NAME = i.INDEX_NAME
where statement_id in ('q1','q2','q3') and OBJECT_NAME is not NULL
and p.OBJECT_NAME not like ':%' /* suppress parallel row sources */
order by 1,2;

OBJECT_OWNER TABLE_NAME
------------ ----------
DWH          A          
DWH          B          
DWH          C          
DWH          D
```

Final note, this approach work only if all queries and views are syntactically valid and you have a user with enough rights to explain plan for all the queries from your list.

Comment: Footnote: There is potentially a difference between tables in the execution plan and tables in the query.  The optimizer can eliminate tables entirely from an execution plan, so you can get spurious results.  One quick trick is to create a view based on your SQL, and then query USER_DEPENDENCIES for the view.  This will show the objects required, whether they are eliminated from the execution plan or not.

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald excellent idea and also much simpler to perform. Thanks very much for sharing!